# Python Markdown module choking on unicode conversion, utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, markdown

I'm using the markdown module from web2py to handle marked up text. The problem is, people are submitting stuff with smartquotes, special characters etc, and I need to replace those with their equivalents.

I have text like this: '\n\r\nThe Colonels face paled a bit. \xe2\x80\x9cBut, then \xe2\x80" excuse my boldness, sir \xe2\x80" our going to Uvar now'

How do I ensure that calling unicode(txt, 'utf-8') like it does on the text internally inside markdown will not throw an error? The fancy special quotes that word processing programs insert are the normal cause, but there seem to be many characters which are an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `\xe2\x80\x9c` is U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (a "smart quote") when decoded as UTF-8. The two occurrences of `\xe2\x80"` are not valid UTF-8 sequences and the presence there of a `"` (a "dumb" quote) is suspicious. You appear to have a mangling problem or an encoding problem, or both. We need to sort that out before we get to the task of replacing e.g. smart quotes by dumb quotes.

Exactly how are "people submitting stuff"? What transformations has it gone through before markdown does `unicode(txt, 'utf-8')`?

Comment: The typical culprit is Microsoft Word, which by default changes quotes to smart quotes.  Since pasting Word generated text into Microsoft Notepad removes bolding, underlying, etc., many folks incorrectly presume it uses exclusively "plain text" (which was never clearly defined BTW) and/or ASCII.  Notepad does NOT remove smart quotes since it uses Code Page1252, which, at least in the 3rd generation, defines glyphs in the illegal 0x80-0x9F including the infamous smart quote.